# 32-bit fixed point overflow

Tags: math, intel, integer-arithmetic

I'm doing some 'early computing' on a 32-bit Windows PC, and looking at the limits.

Now, 2**32 is 4,294,967,296, and I find that

```
4294967290 + 5
```

is perfectly OK, and

```
    4294967290 + 6
```

quite properly overflows.

What puzzles me is that

```
   429496729 * 10
```

overflows, although the product, 4294967290, is in range.

Anyone interested?

Comment: what environment are you using? Your compiler / interpreter may be doing some inexact bounds checking.

Comment: That's not fixed point by the way, it's integer. Fixed point is integer with scaling (for example, 100 = 1.00, 4323 = 43.23, and so on).

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absense of any code, I'd guess `429496729` gets implicitly typed as signed integer, for which `4294967290` is too much.

Comment: You beat me to it. The result is probably negative to prove it.

Comment: Thanks fellows, quite right.  Actually there was no code, but the Visual C 6 debugger watch window (used for my 'probing') evaluates numeric integers as signed.  Quite reasonably actually.  All is well with unsigned int.